# É possivel adicionar classes extras a uma dll?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mingw

O compilador até consegue compilar perfeitamente , mas por algum motivo quando executo o `app.exe` me retorna um erro, segue o meu codigo:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cpp.h"

int main() {
  ClassA * a = new ClassA();
  std::cout << "Versao : " << a->version() << std::endl;
  delete a;
  return 0;
}
```

**cpp.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER
class ClassA {
public:
  int val;
  ClassA ();
  int version();
};
#endif
```

**cpp.cpp**

```
#include "cpp.h"

class ClassB {
public:
  int val;
  ClassB() {
    val = 15;
  }
};

ClassA::ClassA() {
  ClassB * b = new ClassB();
  val = b->val;
  delete b;
}

int ClassA::version() {
  return val;
}
```

Eu compilo no `mingw-64` utilizando os seguintes comandos:

`g++ -shared -fpic cpp.cpp -o cpp.dll`

`g++ -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc main.cpp cpp.dll -o app.exe`

O `app.exe` quando executado  mostra um erro "O aplicativo não pôde ser inicializado corretamente (0xc000007b)". Se eu remover `ClassB`, e colocar o valor em `val` diretamente ele funciona normalmente, o que me fez pensar que 
 acrescentar uma classe fora do header comum viola o link.

Comment: Acrescente á pergunta o erro que dá quando executa o `app.exe`

Comment: Eu copiei e executei teu codigo aqui e funcionou de boa, fiz no Linux direto. So tive que tirar o `-static` do teu comando de compilacao.

Comment: me parece que o mingw exige que libstdc++ seja compilado estaticamente tbm na dll

Comment: Por questão de teste, compilar o arquivo `cpp` para `.obj` e depois por para compilar junto do `main`, funciona?

Comment: não, da a mesma coisa

Answer (score 1):

Nas atualizações mais recentes o MinGw faz a ligação com a biblioteca padrão do c++ de modo dinamico por padrão. Neste caso a dll gerada também fica dependente dinamicamente desta biblioteca, me parece que a dll está tentando carregar-la visto que o aplicativo não mostra esse erro caso a "libgcc_s_seh-1.dll" esteja no mesmo diretório.

Para resolver isso bastou mudar o código de compilação para :

`g++ -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -shared -fpic cpp.cpp -o cpp.dll`

O erro não acontecia se a `ClassB` fosse removida porque eu também removia operador `new` , o que removia a dependência da biblioteca stdc++ !!!

Answer (score 0):

A estrutura do código não é a mais correta, deverias ter um ficheiro cpp (c plus plus/c++) e um ficheiro h (header) por cada classe. O teu problema (sem ver o erro) diria que se trata de inclusão circular, além da estrutura.
O ficheiro .h server para criares a definição da classe, enquanto que o ficheiro cpp serve para se implementar a lógica da classe (apenas da classe!!).
Por isso diria para criares o ficheiro ClassA.cpp, ClassA.h, ClassB.cpp, ClassB.h e chamares a lógica na classe Main.

ClassA.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H
class ClassA {
   public:
   int val;
   ClassA ();
   int version();
};
#endif
```

ClassA.cpp

```
ClassA::ClassA() {
   ClassB * b = new ClassB();
   val = b->val;
  delete b;
}

int ClassA::version() {
   return val;
}
```

A ClasseB também precisa de estar em outros ficheiros.